# Different css based on what is behind element

Tags: css, overflow, pseudo-element

I'm trying to apply different styles to a link based on it's location overlapping an absolutely positioned background div.

Specifically, when the link overlaps the yellow section here, I want to apply different CSS:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp1zG.png

I was trying to figure out how to make this work with a higher z-index pseudo element that would be cut off with an overflow:hidden, but clearly that won't work because the link itself is parent.

Any thoughts or solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: This is actually the desired effect:
https://i.imgur.com/4kyxoHR.png

The text-shadow and box-shadow properties need to differ when over the yellow box.

Answer (score 0):

What you try cannot be done with CSS.

To solve this problem nevertheless, I would give the link a white AND a yellow underline. If they are only one pixel high, this might not be noticeable.

```
a {border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;}
a > span  {border-bottom: 1px solid white;}
```

Comment: I'm not a believer in "impossible" but this is really boggling my mind. Any idea anyone?